Buildozer.spec what requirements should use for Sripe
On the left side of the pic I have all the modules I used for my Kivy app on the right side   the buildozer.spec requirements when I run my app on android phone it crash, and if i remove import Stripe I run until I use the function that uses stripe, how can I solve it . here is the link of the image below
https://i.sstatic.net/tVWFlryf.png

Hi, just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you
